# rsync icloud drive folder

Tags: rsync, icloud-drive

I wanted to use rsync to compare files from a local folder with a folder on the icloud drive.

But icloud drive files that are only online, have a different name

original:
file-name.txt

when the file is only on the cloud:
.file-name.txt.icloud